# Designer view in Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, ide, xamarin.forms

I just wanted to know that, is it possible to get the designer view in Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2015. It's very hard to compile code every time to check the simple changes.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAML to write the code you can use XAML Previewer for Xamarin.Forms You can see the documentation here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Few things to keep in mind:

1. You need to be connected to MAC Agent to make it work (I am not sure
   why this is the case even for Android, For me it does not work without connecting to mac agent)
2. The Previewer works on any ContentPage, ContentView, or ViewCell in
   a   Xamarin.Forms application
3. To launch the Previewer in Visual Studio, select View -> Other
   Windows -> Xamarin.Forms Previewer
4. Latest-and-greatest Xamarin.Forms NuGet is recommended; at least
   2.3.2 is required
5. Project should be built (compiled) before attempting to preview XAML
   files.
6. This is a "Preview" release, so it may not always work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I have followed the above steps but I didn't get the option to enable `Xamarin.Forms Previewer` here are screenshots of my projects 1. View  [Menu](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzH4rCQXcUswaURCa1RNSno4VVk/view?usp=sharing) 2. I have installed the latest version of Xamarin.Forms from [NuGet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzH4rCQXcUswRWlWeTdncnB0d1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other  and select Stable channel and click on check now, see if there are any updated avail, if so do it

Comment: Thanks, I got the update but due to slow internet connection, will download tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Thank You Dakshal, I got the Xamarin.Forms Previewer now and Also my 1 other is also resolved, I can connect Xamarin with Mac now. However, I can't mark your answer due to restriction in reputation. If possible please mark my question.

Comment: Thank you so much sir :)

Comment: No Problem, Glad I could help.